# gcc and linking files with CFLAGS

Tags: gcc, makefile

I am trying to run program from the Learn C Hard Way book

I need to pass the library filename 'build/liblcthw.a' as the last parameter.

For eg :

Doesnt Work on Ubuntu :

gcc -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -DNDEBUG build/liblcthw.a tests/list_tests.c -o tests/list_tests

Works on Ubuntu :

gcc -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -DNDEBUG tests/list_tests.c -o tests/list_tests build/liblcthw.a

How do I handle this in Makefile ? CFLAGS will only add it before the source filename and it doesnt work. How do I force CFALGS to add the library filename at the end of the command ?

Answer (score 3):

CFLAGS are flags for the C compiler. Libraries typically go into a variable called LDLIBS. Set LDLIBS=build/liblcthw.a and see if that works.

Comment: +1. In automake parlance, LIBS or LDADD is also a common term.

Answer (score 2):

The first invocation doesn't succeed because the order of sources and libraries in the command line is wrong. The correct order is source files, then object files, followed by static libraries followed by dynamic libraries.